# What is com.google.android.gsf.login?

Tags: google

Com.google.android.gsf.login. I seen this in my history and am having trouble figuring out what it is. Can you please help me ?

Comment: *Google Services Framework Login*. It comes with the label *Google Account Manager*. Search "Google Services Framework" on web to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

## **com.google.android.gsf.login**

Is part of the Google Services framework and one of the main components of any GApps package. It is basically the account manager for all things needing a login with Google credentials. If you disable or remove this app you will no longer have access to the Play Store nor any other app/service requiring those credentials.